# Transform Last N Elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml structure

```
         <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="21 /en/" enabled="false">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">moulin.nl</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">443</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/en/</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Detected a redirect from the previous sample</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.image_parser">true</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy[3]/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
```

I want to have following transformation(s)

1) Replace `<collectionProp reference ... />` with `<collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">` element.

2) Remove `<elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" ... >` with children

3) The above xml-structure (`HTTPSamplerProxy`-`hashTree` combo - siblings) repeat many times in one xml file, so above two points should be applicable to all repeated xml-structures (`HTTPSamplerProxy`-`hashTree` combo - siblings).

4) Also is it possible to select last N xml-strucutres (`HTTPSamplerProxy`-`hashTree` combo - siblings)

I have tried *few* xslt transformations but couldn't able to achieve desire result.

Now below is whole xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="3.2" jmeter="3.2 r1790748">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="LoopController.loops">1</intProp>
        </elementProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testname="17 /en/" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="17 /en/" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">moulin.nl</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/en/</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Detected the start of a redirect chain</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.image_parser">true</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="18 /en/" enabled="false">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">moulin.nl</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">443</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/en/</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Detected a redirect from the previous sample</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.image_parser">true</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy[2]/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <GenericController guiclass="LogicControllerGui" testname="19 /" enabled="true"/>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="19 /" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">moulin.nl</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Detected the start of a redirect chain</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.image_parser">true</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="20 /" enabled="false">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">moulin.nl</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">443</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Detected a redirect from the previous sample</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.image_parser">true</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy[2]/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testname="21 /en/" enabled="false">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">moulin.nl</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">443</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/en/</stringProp>
            <elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" elementType="HeaderManager" guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
                <elementProp name="Cache-Control" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Cache-Control</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept-Encoding" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept-Encoding</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">gzip</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Pragma" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Pragma</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">no-cache</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="User-Agent" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">User-Agent</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
                <elementProp name="Accept" elementType="Header">
                  <stringProp name="Header.name">Accept</stringProp>
                  <stringProp name="Header.value">text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2</stringProp>
                </elementProp>
              </collectionProp>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Detected a redirect from the previous sample</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.image_parser">true</boolProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp reference="../../../HTTPSamplerProxy[3]/elementProp[2]/collectionProp"/>
            </HeaderManager>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Comment: The requirements are not very clear. What do you mean by Remove `<elementProp name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" ... >`, is it just the `<elementProp>` element or is it the element and it's children too? `<HttpSamplerProxy>` and `<hashTree>` combo means which pair? In the XML these elements are siblings as well as child-parent. Please share the XSLT code you have tried so far. It will be helpful to suggest fixes as well as we would be able to understand the logic behind handling the requirements.

Comment: @AniketV Thanks for comment, Delete `<elementProp 
name="HTTPSampler.header_manager" ... >` with children. `HttpSamplerProxy>` and `<hashTree>` combo means siblings.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Appreciate if you can share the XSLT code as well. Please edit the question and add the XSLT code you have tried so far.

Comment: I will share the xslt code(s) in the edit as soon as I am home.